# year not working in Javascript code

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this code. I'm not fluent in JS so I need some help getting a permanent solution. The wrong year was being displaying until I changed line 5 in the full code shown at the bottom. I made the code change a couple weeks ago but it suddenly stopped working.

I changed line 5 from:

```
 if (myDate.getMonth() < 10) {
```

To:

```
 if (myDate.getMonth() < 1) {
```

It worked and I have no idea why.

Here is the full code. I suspect my code change will eventually stop working.

Can anyone offer a better solution?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+1);
if (myDate.getMonth() < 1) {
    var betterMonth = "0" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1);
} else {
    var betterMonth = (myDate.getMonth() + 1);          
}

var prettyDate =  betterMonth + '/' + (myDate.getDate()) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
$("#formDelivery").val(prettyDate);         

$("#formPhoneNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");           
$("#contactPhoneNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");            

jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
    phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
    }, "Please specify a valid phone number");

$("#orderForm").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        }
    }
});
$("#formDelivery").mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder:"_"}).datepicker({ minDate: +14 });
```

});

Comment: What is considered "working"? What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: You have not said what your problem is, but I'm assuming you want your months pre-zeroing.  You can do something like -> `var betterMonth = ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);`  and get rid of your if altogether.  Oh, and you can of course do the same for the getDate(). :)

Comment: Are you sure your problem is with the year, not the month?

Comment: @Barmar Agreed. Just mentioned this in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the line you changed...

```
if (myDate.getMonth() < 10) {
   var betterMonth = "0" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1);
```

This says "If the current month is less than 10", and its intention is to add leading 0's to single-digit months. The problem I see here is that `getMonth()` returns is a 0-index list of months, and so 0 is actually January, 1 is February, so on and so forth.

That in mind:

The code `if (myDate.getMonth() < 10) {` is really saying "If the current month is less than *November*, then add a preceding 0". When you said that the wrong "year" is being returned, did you mean *"month"*? Because I'm quite certain this code would output `010` for October instead of `10`.

I believe it should be...

```
if (myDate.getMonth() < 9) {
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mmjeehxe/)

---

Armed with this knowledge, you may now realize why your fix worked. Changing the number to a "1" will only add preceding 0's if the month is before February. Your solution would work up until February rolled around, and you'd start seeing `2/01/2016` instead of `02/01/2016`.